# Subtract a number more than once

Tags: c#

I am fairly new to programming and would like to know how I can get my program to subtract 30 from 100 every time I click a button. This is what I have but can't seem to find the correct formula.

```
        int hpLevel = 100;
        int hpDrop = 30;

        if (hpLevel > 0)
        {
            lblHpLevel.Text = Convert.ToString(hpLevel - hpDrop);
        }
        else
        {
            lblHpLevel.Text = Convert.ToString(hpLevel);
        }
```

Comment: How does that not do what you want?  Might want to do the math as a separate step.

Comment: Store your new value in hpLevel, *then* put that value in the textbox.

Comment: @Plutonix 100-30 = 70 no matter how many times you run it.

Comment: errr The point was that the Op did not describe a problem nor ask a question.  It might not do anything at all if that code is not where it needs to be

Comment: My answer is 70 but I would like it to subtract again when I click the button again so my answer would be from 70 to 40 until I reach 0.

Comment: Use `-=` instead of `-` to assign the result of the subtraction to the hpLevel variable.

Comment: Just tried that, sadly it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code declares a new `hpLevel` variable every time the button is clicked. You want that variable defined *outside of the method*, at the class level, so that the value will be retained between clicks.

Additionally, the code never assigns the result back to the `hpLevel` variable. It assigns it directly to the TextBox, while `hpLevel` is never changed. You need to assign the results to `hpLevel` and then set that value to your textbox.

```
int hpLevel = 100;
int hpDrop = 30;

void button1_Click( ... )
{
    if (hpLevel > 0)
    {
        hpLevel -= hpDrop;  
    }
    lblHpLevel.Text = Convert.ToString(hpLevel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must declare `int hpLevel = 100` out of the scope of the method that is handling the `click event`. If  `int hpLevel = 100` is part of the aformentioned method then you are instantiating  an `int`variable with name `hpLevel` and assigning it the value `100` every time you click the button.
You can learn about [scopes here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)